# Verify if a value within one column of a recordset exists in another column of a record recordset

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am new to Access and VBA. I have two record set , given table A and table B. Table A has a  single row of data and Table B record set has multiple rows like Below

[image: Image Reference]

I want to write VBA code to display a message box if the value in column CTR_NBR in Table A is present in CTR Table B .

Upon some research I have come up with the below code but it throws a type mismatch error ,

```
    Dim dbs as DAO.Database
    Dim rst_A as DAO.Recordset
    Dim rst_B as DAO.Recordset 


    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst_A = OpenRecordset("Table A")
    Set rst_B = OpenRecordset("Table B")

    If rst_A.Fields(0).Value = rst.Fields(2).Value Then

    Msgbox ("Value exists in Table B")

    Else 
  
    Msgbox ("Value does not exist in Table B")

    End If
```

I was expecting the message boxes to show up but stead a got a type mismatch error. Is there a way to write this code differently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DLookup` for such simple tasks:

```vb
    Dim CtrNbr As Long
    Dim Prompt As String

    CtrNbr = DLookup("[CTR_NBR]", "[Table A]", "[CTR_NBR] Is Not Null")

    If IsNull(DLookup("[DPT_ID]", "[Table B]", "[CTR_NBR] = " & CtrNbr & "")) Then
        Prompt = "Value does not exist in Table B"
    Else  
        Prompt = "Value exists in Table B"
    End If
    MsgBox Prompt
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
FUNCTION EXIST() AS BOOLEAN
    EXIST= (DCOUNT("CTR_NBR" , "TABLE_B" , "CTR_NBR=" & DFIRST("CTR_NBR" , "TABLE_A")) > 0)
END FUNCTION
```

**Solution 2:**

```
FUNCTION EXIST() AS BOOLEAN
DIM RS AS RECORDSET
SET RS= CURRENTDB.OPENRECORDSET("SELECT COUNT(B.DPT_ID) AS N FROM TABLE_A A INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.CTR_NBR=B.CTR_NBR")
    EXIST= (RS!N > 0)
RS.CLOSE
SET RS= NOTHING
END FUNCTION
```

**Solution 3:**

Create a query named QRY_EXIST as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(B.DPT_ID) AS N FROM TABLE_A A INNER JOIN TABLE_B B ON A.CTR_NBR=B.CTR_NBR
```

And use it in the following function:

```
FUNCTION EXIST() AS BOOLEAN
    EXIST= (DFIRST("N" , "QRY_EXIST") > 0)
END FUNCTION
```

**Usage:**

```
If EXIST Then
    Msgbox ("Value exists in Table B")
Else 
    Msgbox ("Value does not exist in Table B")
End If
```

Joining tables on CTR_NBR already mentioned in comments.